# OpenSSL encrypt is ok, but decrypt is false

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

first, im sorry for my bad English.

Im forced to use OpenSSL and im testing it now.

I have public key:

```
$key = "{key}"; 
$key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . wordwrap($key, 64, "\n", true) . "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

When i use:

```
$secret = "test";
$test = openssl_public_encrypt($secret, $encrypted, $key);
```

... everything is ok, in $test is true - so encrypting is ok.

But now, i want decrypt it back, so i use:

```
$ok = openssl_public_decrypt($encrypted, $vys, $key);
```

...and on this place, the $ok variable contains false :(
How it is possible?

Thanks very much to all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should decrypt with `openssl_private_decrypt()`
And you need to provide private key as argument.
Try to read more about [public key encryption](http://www.comodo.com/resources/small-business/digital-certificates2.php) and [openssl_public_encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php)

Comment: Thanks - i have read your links. But where i get matched private key? I have only the public one. And need decrypt data, which have been encrypted by the public one. I obtained only public key, encrypted data, and thats it - by theese i must decrypt data.

Comment: You **must** have the private key in order to decrypt encrypted data. And it's impossible to get the matching private key from public key and encrypted data. You can ask the owner of private key to provide it.